# Gridview must show Text instead of the Value from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that gets the data from a database.
Here is the .NET code. There's a lot of columns, and here the template: Choice is the one I'm talking about.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="EmpID" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" style="margin-right: 81px" Width="1174px" >
       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
       <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choice" SortExpression="Choice">
        <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownChoice" Text='<%# Bind("Choice") %>' runat="server"  Width="60px">
                           <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                           <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblChoice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Choice") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here on the EditItemTemplate, the user may edit the said data on the database. Where I can use a drop down list and show the text as No or Yes but the value that will be saved on the database is still 0 and 1.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownChoice" Text='<%# Bind("Choice") %>' runat="server"  Width="60px">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I'm having trouble of showing the text No and Yes on the Gridview once it runs. As you can see here is the ItemTemplate code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblChoice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Choice") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

> Please suggest a way/method to show No/Yes on the ItemTemplate/Gridview section once executed. Thanks (let me know if you might need the C# code to bind data on the gridview)

NOTE:
I have tried the RowDataBound event that was answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702062/gridview-display-the-text-instead-of-values).
here is the code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        System.Data.DataRow dr = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

        if (dr["Choice"].ToString() == "0")
        {
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblChoice")).Text = "No";
        }
        else if (dr["Choice"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblChoice")).Text = "Yes";
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Am I missing something? Do I have to include something in the `<ItemTemplate>` tag ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gridview display the text instead of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702062/gridview-display-the-text-instead-of-values)

Comment: @iceDragon I have actually tried the RowDataBound Event from that article, but I im afraid it wasnt been point out to the answer how to call it to the .Net? do you know how? thanks (i'll also edit this question and include this)

Comment: You add the event to the GridView tool like this <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>

Comment: Thank you! Probably I need 20 more reputations so I can comment on that question to ask what else I need to add , so its only the OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"

Comment: You are welcome, yes that's it you add the event call in the gridView tag and then edit the code to meet your requirements. I think your code should be running smoothly. do you have another problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you can either use Render Property function or row data bound event.

[RenderProperty Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6702318/609731)

[RowDataBound Event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6702672/609731)

Both answers are from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702062/gridview-display-the-text-instead-of-values)

Edit: As you asked how to call the RowDataBound event, it's added to the GridView tag like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Dang. I have added it and that's it! It's that easy! ughhhThanks mate, you saved me :D

Answer (score 1):

Without using RowBound event you can do this

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblChoice" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("Choice").Equals("1")? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and im having error on the .equals , what am I might missing? Do I have to add any reference or anything? thanks again

Comment: I tried it and I got the error: " The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context" , I tried replacing it with Eval instead of Bind, it runs now but only giving results of=No, even though I have 1/Yes in the context.

Comment: It would be great if you can help me further, I just found out that some of my codes are not compatible with the RowDataBound event and im having error in the runtime

Comment: I got it, here's what ive done : `Text='<%# Eval("Served").ToString()== "1" ? "Yes" : "No" %>'>` Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: its on my previous comment, it says: " The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context" and my program wont run.